# RestApi extension/plugin webservices to get/post data from ecommerce site to make moblie app

Tags: android, rest, magento, e-commerce, opencart

I want to create a mobile application native android/ios which take data from the ecommerce server like magento. opencart, joomla, drupal using Rest Service.

Services like User:

```
    User Registeration
    Login
    Cart
    Products
    Product Categories
    Payment (Using native payment sdk ios/android)
```

Is there plugin/extension for using Rest Services? and which ecommerce platform is good for these tasks?

Or

Is there any other way to make native app for the ecommerce site?

Actually I am not familiar with these ecommerce sites/CMS because I am an Android developer but it's my research task but could not find any good tutorial/link.

Sorry my English skills are not good.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the persons downvoted my question without any comment? Is it necessory to downvote question instead of explain what's wrong in this question?

Answer (score 0):

The REST services can be written in any of the above mentioned languages. Now your problem is parsing the data.
Android provides powerful volley libraries for handling network related work.
Follow the official link below:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html 
Also once the data is received you can use Gson to parse the data into your model.
There is a library named Retrofit that makes your work a bit easy. 
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Actually I am asking about the Extension/Plugin of ecommerce sites which give men data. I am aware of data parsing library but don't know about the plugin/extension which give me data. Like I don't want that a person writes custom webservices to get post data .

Comment: @RameshKumar do you have any idea..?

Comment: @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj sorry I don't have. I did not find any REST services so custom services implemented for mobile.

Comment: @RameshKumar can I have your mailID pls.

Comment: @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj, ramesh.approxen@gmail.com